# index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

We currently don't have a programmer at my work and I am getting the following error. "Index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection" From what I can tell it seems to be an issue with the size of the frame. Am I correct in assuming that? I believe this is the code in question, but I am not a programmer at all. Just trying to get this working in the meantime. I believe the site is asp.net and made in visual web developer 2010

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" title="Time Card" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<iframe id="iHoppp"
        src="http://fs/ihoppp/timecard2"
        frameborder="No" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="2000px" marginheight="5px" marginwidth="5px">
</iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not the iframe, but could be within the content of the iframe.  That is a server-side error that can happen for a variety of reasons, and could be due to the content in the iframe, or something within the current page.  Hard to tell from that, do you have a stack trace of the error in the log?  A more detailed error message would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Brian. That is the entire error message and only one user who started today is getting it. I could show the code behind the default page within the timecard2 that is referenced. Is that what you need? Sorry I don't have more knowledge on this. @BrianMains

Comment: The picture is the entire error message I mean.

Comment: Oh sorry.  Didn't realize that.. the picture is broken for me.  Since it works for @Matthew, I assume a proxy is blocking it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was our IIS site connects the AD and SQL accounts together, but for some reason when it automatically created the connection it got the name wrong. Updating this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the backend code in one of the OnClick events.  The error arises when the code attempts to access an item in an indexed object (like an array) but the object cannot be referenced because it does not exist.

For example, let's say you have an array object called `myColorArray` that contains the names of colors.  The colors in the array are "red", "green", and "blue".  The array object now has 3 items and you can reference the items by its index.  In .NET, all indexed objects start with 0, not 1, so the items in the array can be referenced like this:

```
myColorArray[0]  //contains "red"
myColorArray[1]  //contains "green"
myColorArray[2]  //contains "blue"
```

If you tried to access indexed item 3 in this array, you will get the error you are seeing.

Based on the Stack Trace, it looks like the exception is happening after you clicked the button `btnLogin` on the Default page of the website.  The backend code is attempting to populate a GridView with data when the exception occurs.

Comment: Why would it only be doing it for one user and how would I rectify it? I'll try and find the code it's having issues with to post on here.

Comment: If it is only happening for one user then that points to a user specific data problem.  For example, a page that displays the documents a user has permissions to view.